# Height 100% again

Tags: css, height

Note: I have read lots of articles but still can not find elegant solution... Please help.
I have the following code for the menu:

```
<ul id="xx">
 <li><a href="href1">Link1</a></li>
 <li><a href="href2">Link2</a></li>
 <li><a href="href3">Link3</a></li>
 ...
 <li><a href="hrefn">Linkn</a></li>
</ul>
```

This displays without any CSS as just bulleted list of links. That's good.
Now I want to use CSS, and have the following layout: whole ul to be horizontal bar, with li being cells in the bar, with links occupying whole cells in this bar.
Great, I use

```
#xx {margin:0px;padding:0px;text-align:center;display:table;width:100%}
#xx li{padding:1px;list-style-type:none;display:table-cell;border-left:2px solid white;vertical-align:middle}
```

and that gives me the table. Excellent. Now I want a element to occupy whole space of the li (table-cell). And this is what I am smashing my head over for several days already. Here's my latest writing:

```
#xx a{display:block;color:white;text-decoration:none;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:blue;vertical-align:middle;}
```

but the a still does not fill the space!

I tried position relative/absolute - does not work, and a kind of flawed. adding another span or div within a is stupid.

Any good ideas? Thanks!

IMPORTANT EDIT: I also need text in the a's being vertically centered.

ANOTHER EDIT: height is dynamic and is based on the contents of a element.

ANOTHER EDIT 1: need IE support.

ANOTHER EDIT 2: the purpose of a to be of the same height and width of parent element (li) is the whole area to be clickable through a's href.

Comment: Have you tried to put for your #xx li display: inline-block ?

Comment: then whole construction stops being a horizontal bar... outer display:table and inner display:inline-block creates two rows. But actually you nailed the issue - if there would be only TWO levels (ul and a), then first is table and second is table-cell. BUT there're three levels, thus as I see it can only be achieved as ul being table, li being table-cell and a being something I do not know what which fills entire parent table-cell!

Comment: what about the 1px padding on li ?

Comment: sorry just added clarification... content is dynamic, height of whole bar is the height of "tallest" text in any of cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display:flex; could be a way for younger browser. **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/mBxts)**

You need an extra markup to center/middle the text inside your link.
HTML test base :

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="href1">
      <span>Link1</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="href2">
      <span>Link2</span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="href3">
      <span>Link3 
        <br/> 
        line 2
      </span>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="hrefn"><span>Link4</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And CSS basis:

```
ul {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;/* defaut display in rows */
  background:red; /* will you see it ? */
  padding:0;
}
li {
  display:flex;/* so <a> strectch/expand */
  flex:1;/* all even sized */
  border-left:2px solid white;
}
ul li a { 
  display:flex;/* again, to use margin auto to center child in middle center */
  flex:1;
  background:gray;
}
ul li a span {
  margin:auto;/* let me center middle myseldf */
  display:block;/* i need to be a block to be centered via margin:auto; */
}
```

**Notice** `display:flex` used on almost every level to benefits its particularities: strectching an element to fit all space or shrink it downwith  `margin:auto` to center & middle .

---

*for older browser you can use display:table as a CSS fallback and pseudo elements to increase areas where link can be clicked : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Lusnd/*

Comment: Absolutely correct... IE8 is completely screwed up.

Comment: display:table/table-cell is tour friend for a acceptable fallback :)

Comment: did not get it, sorry

Comment: okay: first, if you want to use just display:table and if background o f <a> is a plaine color, then this will work just fine : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/lLIJa for IE8 : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/LwDHq

Comment: Looks great... but a does not occupy the space. The purpose is whole area to be clickable using a (BTW I currently have this implementation, and make bar cells clickable through JS, but need to go pure CSS without onclicks)

Comment: If you will look into element inspector, you will see that text "Link x" is long, but low horizontal bar at the center of the tall cell, and only this bar is clickable. The target is whole blue area should be clickable through a element. Do you see the point?

Comment: @Anonymous yes i saw, just forgot to check on it , z-index is resquired. demo updated and here another demo http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Lusnd/ with display:table override by display:flex. display:table comes here as a fallback for browser that do not understand flex model. ::after not understood by IE is there to erase :after unneeded in the flex model. hope you understood the part : CSS fallback :)

Comment: Thank you. I tried on my live example and it seems working in both chrome and IE8 (the only change on 2 columns I had to increase negative margin and positive border). Can you explain theory? I guess that you extend area of a (why :before?) to huge size and then hide what's outside of li with overflow hidden. But why you need positioning and z-index? Margin, border?

Comment: you get it, pseudo is used to increase area used by the link. set in absolute position, it diesnt destroy the general layout. I use it for folding menus that are too small to increase area wehre mouse over can be catch, so menu doesn't disseapear cause mouse was 1 pixel away from the border. Iused negative margin here, cause display:table and psoition:relativedoesn't go along well with Firefox , don't mind it if you use both display:table/flex, FF will take the flex properties and will erase the pseudo

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `a` element set the height for the whole menu and let the other elements adapt to it, here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d6rkR/

```
ul{
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%
}
li{
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
a{
    display: block;
    line-height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: height is dynamic, and based on the contents of a

Answer (score 0):

As @GCyrillus pointed out `display:flex` can be a suitable solution, here's a version that doesn't alter the original markup (only tested on Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/d6rkR/1/

```
ul{
    display: flex;
}
li{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
a{
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```